# Downloading files in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am using the code recommended by Microsoft.

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("mydlurl", "C:\jb\jb.exe")
```

But that throws an unhandled exception on my friends computer, and some other people, but some can use it.

I tried using downloadasync with a progress bar, but it freezes before it even starts.(Does nothing)

Here is my code that runs an unhandled exception on some computers.

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\jb\jb.exe") Then
Else
    'jbinfo.Text = "Please wait as your file is being downloaded."
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download1580.mediafire.com/g/abcdefghijklmnop/myfile.exe", "C:\jb\jb.exe", "", "", True, 500, True) '<Maybe fix. Lets try.
End If
```

The exception message is:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
    just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

    ************** Exception Text **************
    System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
      at     Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.Internal.WebClientCopy.DownloadFile(Uri address, String destinationFileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.DownloadFile(Uri address, String destinationFileName, ICredentials networkCredentials, Boolean showUI, Int32 connectionTimeout, Boolean overwrite, UICancelOption onUserCancel)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.DownloadFile(String address, String destinationFileName, String userName, String password, Boolean showUI, Int32 connectionTimeout, Boolean overwrite, UICancelOption onUserCancel)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.DownloadFile(String address, String destinationFileName, String userName, String password, Boolean showUI, Int32 connectionTimeout, Boolean overwrite)
   at MyApp.Main.Button1_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Which exception - type and message?

Comment: So can i use a different hosting service, or my own?

Comment: Wrong place for a comment? Should be under below answer?

Comment: @user3051640 yes you could use a different host or host your own website somewhere. Though other hosts might have similar protections in place.

Answer (score 0):

If I run this I get a `ProtocolViolation`, this is probably because DownloadFile expects a `200 OK`, followed by the download, but Mediafire is sending you a `302 FOUND` instead and redirects the request to a new location where the download page for this download is.

This is to prevent you from using MediaFire as a file hosting platform to distribute files without people actually knowing you're using MediaFire (makes sense right?).

You won't be able to use `wc.DownloadFile` or any other .NET framework method that expects a file here. You'll need to actually implement the proper 'handshake' with Mediafire so to speak, so they send you a new location, then go there and show that to the users.